# Is it correct to say "Luke can't swim today, he is having a cold"?

Tags: tense, present-tense, continuous

Is the continuous form of "have" ok in the sentence "he's having a cold"? Or is it ONLY correct and possible to say "He has a cold"? 
I can't figure out if in this case "have a cold" is a state verb or not. If it were, it couldn't have the continuous form.

Comment: have a cold in not used in the continuous form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some verbs have two different meanings or senses. For one sense we cannot use a continuous tense. For the other sense we can use any tense.

**In sense 1** there is no real action, no activity. This sense is called "stative". **In sense 2** there is a kind of action, a kind of activity. This sense is called "dynamic"

to  have: 
1.  I  have  a  pound  now.  (Non-Continuous  Verb: I  possess  a  pound.)

2. I  am having  fun  now. ( Normal  Verb: I  am experiencing  fun  now.)
3. I can’t answer the phone, I’m having a   bath. (Normal  Verb: I’m taking)
4. We will be having a party on Friday.

Therefore, the answer is: He has a cold.

Answer (score 0):

Colds cannot be continuously had. You have to use the simple present to describe when someone currently has a cold, *ie*, "[Luke] has a cold."